# Excel VBA - Filtering Values

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a code in VBA to filter my data in a column in order to perform regression. Down below is a snapshot of the data. I am trying to filter the data such that I am going from the most recent date (Jan-13) and backwards trying to find values with greater than 10% change. By change I mean, (Absolute value (Recent_Date_Rate - Older_Date_Rate))/Recent_Date_Rate > 10%.

I have accomplished writing a code that would give me all the noise values (bad numbers with less than <10% change in steam rate). All it does is, compare the most recent values to the older values and if the change is less than 10% it copies and pastes the value in column R.

My question is really, is there a way for make the code do the opposite? so that only the good values that I intend to use for my regression are printed in column R. I tried changing the operator (>) to this, but that didnt work.

**Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance. Any tips to improve the code would also be appreciated.**

```
Sub main6()

    Range("R:R").ClearContents

    Dim offset1 As Integer
    Dim offset2 As Integer

    For j = Range("P1").Value To 3 Step -1
        offset1 = Cells(j, "P").Row - 3
        offset2 = Range("P1").Value - Cells(j, "P").Row
        For k = 1 To offset1
            If Abs((Cells(j, "P").Value - Cells(k + 2, "P").Value)) / Cells(j, "P").Value < 0.05 Then
                Cells(k + 2, "P").Copy
                Cells(k + 2, "R").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            End If
        Next k
    Next j
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You say "I tried changing the operator, but that didn't work". What happened? It looks like is _should_ have worked...

Comment: I am getting the exact same results.

Comment: Have you tried `If Not . . . . .`? I hope I understand what you are asking correctly.

Comment: @KDavis I tried using that too in combination of changing the operator sign (< & >). But sadly, that didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, your formula `abs(x-y)/x > 0.1` goes for a direct percentage. In theory it is like `x*1.1 < y OR x/1.1 > y`. While there is the chance that x will be in range for y but y not for x (from 19.4 the difference to 21.5 will be bigger than 10% but the opposite will be less then 10%). Still you are just looking into the past. This way the first value will always be shown. An easy way also could be a formula to do this dynamically.

```
R3: =P3
R4: =IF(COUNTIFS(P$3:P3,">"&P4/1.1,P$3:P3,"<"&P4*1.1),"",P4)
```

R4 can be copied down as you need it.

*Done by phone. May contain errors.*  ;)

Comment: The output will be a list with values which do NOT have any value with less than 10% deviation in the past!